# git hooks — preventing commit to get into topic branch

Tags: git, version-control, githooks

I need to stop commits to happen if the message is not properly formatted.

I know it is possible to do it on the **master** branch with the pre-receive hook.

The problem is that I don't want to do that on the **master** branch, but in a topic one.

I thought of doing it using **git symbolic-ref**.

Let say I have a topic branch called **dev** coming from **master**. If I run '*git symbolic-ref HEAD*' from the git command line in the topic branch, I get '*refs/heads/dev*'.

I was thinking of doing the same in the pre-receive hook to detect from which branch the commit comes from.

I have put this bit of code in the hook:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

my $branch = `git symbolic-ref HEAD`;
print "Branch: $branch \n";
```

But when I commit and the push from the topic branch (i.e.: **dev**), the message I'm getting is:

```
Branch: refs/heads/master
```

...even if the commit comes from the **dev** branch.

What am I doing wrong ? Is this a viable way of achieving my target ?

Comment: The `pre-receive` hook is executed before every push, regardless of branch.  Do you mean you implemented a filter so that it is only executed on the master branch updates?

Comment: I needed to edit the question since it was a bit confusing. I hope now is clearer. I actually need to run certain commands just when the branch updated is not master.